# so I decided to not use namespace anymore, but now when should I add std:: or cv::?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I recently started using c++ and opencv for image processing. since the beginning almost every sample code had using namespace std; in the header. after reading about it I saw that it is recommended not to use namespace since it can lead to problems when two libraries have the same function name.

so I changed it and used cv:: and std:: whenever I got an error but still there were functions from opencv that had no error I assume this is because there's only one function with that name. but should I add the identifier for every function even if this doesn't lead to an error?

for example

```
cv::Mat antif;
idft(complexI, antif);
split(antif, planes);
magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], antif);
normalize(antif, antif, 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
```

I'm measuring the phase difference between two images using Fourier transform.
 I had to add cv:: when making the variable antif. but no error popped up for any of the following functions included in opencv.

is this because there is only one instance of this questions or should I add cv:: just to get used to doing so?

Comment: Be consistent. Either using namespace std; cv or std:: cv:: before every identifier in the namespace.

Comment: Write the code so it can be easily understood by a human. For me, that would mean namespace qualifying all the functions, since then I quickly see what library they belong to.

Comment: Generally speaking, ``using namespace`` statements in a ``cpp`` module is fine. It's putting them in header files that's a real no-no. You can also do stuff in your ``cpp`` like: ``using cv::Mat;`` and then in your source you can keep it ``Mat``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADL has been mentioned in another answer.

Here's how it works:

In the example below, notice that the function `show` has been defined in namespaces `Foo` and `Bar`.

ADL allows the compiler to look in all namespaces mentioned in the argument list.

x1 is a `Foo::X` so in the first call to `show()` the following namespaces may be checked:

- Foo
- :: (the global namespace)
- any namespace pulled into Foo with a using namespace
- any namespace pulled into the global namespace with a `using namespace` (which is why we don't use `using namespace` in the global namespace)

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Foo
{
    struct X{};
    void show(X const&)
    {
        std::cout << "a Foo::X" << std::endl;
    }
}

namespace Bar
{
    struct X{};
    void show(X const&)
    {
        std::cout << "a Bar::X" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto x1 = Foo::X();
    auto x2 = Bar::X();

    show(x1);
    show(x2);
}
```

expected output:

```
a Foo::X
a Bar::X
```

Comment: I didn't know how to search for it. so ADL lets the compiler check in the namespaces. when I removed `using namespace cv`; most of the errors are declarations so ADL doesn't work there. so the ones without errors are functions that ADL could easily found their namespace? and if so should I add `cv::` to avoid problems when adding more libraries?

Comment: @FabricioGomez for declarations you will need to add cv::. When performing function lookups, ADL can be useful in template expansions. However, if you know you need the cv:: version there is no harm in specifying cv:: explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

These functions are found by [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). So, they are in the `cv` namespace, but the compiler is able to guess this because the type of (at least) one of the arguments is in the `cv`namespace.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "guessing"

Comment: It's colloquial for sure, but the article I linked to explains how it works in great detail.

Comment: "deduce" is probably a better word